# bson init from json string with $inc operator

Tags: json, mongodb, bson, mongo-c-driver

I wanna update a document with such a updator(s json string):

```
{"$inc": {"ref": 1}}
```

And I'm using libbson to construct a bson object from that,while the `bson_new_from_json` always failed.However,the `$set` operator is ok,what's wrong with the `$inc` operator?

Answer (score 0):

This is a libbson parsing bug and this pr fixed it: [Fix a bug in json parsing #81](https://github.com/mongodb/libbson/pull/81)